# VSCode Debugging in internal console not working

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, gcc, gdb

I am using VS Code on Windows for my C/C++ assignments at University. I always wanted to debug my code in the integrated VS Code console because for me it is annoying to always have the second window open.
I use the gcc/gdb compiler/debugger.

I already saw some threads on this topic which said, just go into your `launch.json` file and change `"externalConsole":` to true or use `"avoidWindowsConsoleRedirection": false,`. The only thing that changed was that with `"externalConsole": false,` the external terminal window stopped popping up, but I did not get my program output on any of the consoles at the bottom.

`launch.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Test123",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": true,
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "avoidWindowsConsoleRedirection": true,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\mingw\\bin\\gdb.exe",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Automatische Strukturierung und Einrückung für \"gdb\" aktivieren",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please provide full launch.json file and versions of all tools, compilers, debuggers, windows, ...

Comment: @tilz0R sorry, added it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your external console did pop up but your program ended immediately after it started since it ran smoothly without errors, closing the external terminal. Same as if you would double click on your helloworld.exe program.

I would suggest you to add a line `system(pause);` at the end of your program so the external terminal would freeze when your program executes to the end.

Comment: My problem isn't that I can not run my program at all. I just can not run it on the internal console. I can run it just fine on and external console. Also should the internal console not close instantly especially when I set breakpoints.

Comment: What I understand is that you can run your program from a manually opened shelll by entering `.\program.exe` . When you hit f5 with `externalConsole:false` you can see expected output in the vscode debug console. But with `externalConsole: false` , you see nothing after hitting f5. Is this correct?

Comment: Vscode integrated terminal isn't designed to debug stuff, they are just a regular shell. If you don't wish vscode to spawn an external window to debug your program, you should set 'externalConsole： false ' and use the integrated debug console. The integrated terminal doesn't debug your program.

Comment: I do not get any output if i set  `externalConsole:false`, also not on the debug console. I just get an output with `externalConsole:true`, but on the normal external console.